# How to solve basic POST request's java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

Tags: java, json, post

I've a java app who does a POST request to http://evepraisal.com/ and get with Json a "price" value for an item.

My app has 9 item, one button for each item.

When you click on one, display changes and you can see info about current selected item (with in the bottom, this "price" value !)

My problem is : When I click a first time on a button to call a POST request for a specific item, everything works well, but if I change item and then go back to first one I've got an exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
```

this method is called when I click on "Athanor" Item :

```
public void sendAthanorPostRequest() throws IOException {
    //Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(getAthanorUrlParameters());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    Athanor.estSellPrice = jsonObject.getJSONObject("appraisal").getJSONObject("totals").getDouble("sell");
```

Appraisal --> totals --> sell is the value I get from POST request.

I think this problem comes because a connection is already etablished between me and appraisal, 
Am I right ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem resolved : Add a isRequestAlreadyDone boolean, if true then post request will not be used anymore